# Magento Development - Modifying The Image Links on the Navigation Filters

Tags: html, css, magento

I've begun building a Magento store for diamond products which have various attributes that can be selected against the layered navigation filters.

[image: Layered Navigation Filters]

I want to customise the display of these so that they look something like the following:

[image: Desired Filter]

I was prepared to do this using CSS, however the issue is that it looks like the Magento layered navigation filters do not have anything that I can identify each option on:

[image: Issue]

Could anybody please help me out and point me in the right direction or possibly somebody has some advice on how I would begin about achieving this? Thank you so much for taking your time to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to include swatches in the frontend

make a atribute global and filterable with result(I guess, Which you did already)
then Navigate to the System > Configuration > Configurable Swatches and enable the module. The configuration enables swatches,select your attribute.

Then navigate to the cms pages and add the swatches to it first of all put the swatches in the media/wysiwyg/swatches  swatch directory using editor.
and upload same name png icons/images as product attribute.

Comment: Hi Shrikant, thank you for taking time to answer. The problem with this as far as I'm aware is that swatch images have to be defined by their dimension in the catalog settings. As you can see from the example in my post, the images are different shapes and sizes. Am I incorrect about this? If so, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If you  want to change template file, you can turn on template path hints. Then see the corresponding classes used for it and make changes in CSS file, hope this will solve your purpose

Comment: Hi Shrikant. I'm not sure but I'll have a look. Thanks for your help.